# git rebase and file conflict

Tags: git, github, rebase

After doing my work in my branch, I made pull request to merge my branch in to master. Github show one file of my branch has conflict and can not be automatically merged.
On the other hand, my manager asked me to rebase my branch. I did rebase as following:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
$ git checkout my-baranch
$ git rebase master
```

I get CONFLICT message in one file. I resolved the conflict and did

```
$ git rebase --continue
```

Rebase done successfully. Now I'm not sure what to do next. My PR is still showing one conflicted file and can not be merge automatically.

I just want to know what to do next after rebase so My PR could automatically be merged.

Comment: You've done the hard part. Now you need to do the easy part. The hard part was the rebase. The easy part is: you need to *discard* the old pull request and make a *new* pull request from the rebased branch. You can do that literally: close the old request and open a new one. Or you can do it by force-pushing the pull-request name, i.e., instead of tossing PR#123 and creating PR#124, you *overwrite* the old PR#123. I'd go with close-and-reopen, as I think it's clearer, though it takes slightly more work.

Answer (score 1):

checkout your branch , make upstream as master . Then rebase/merge the upstream and fix the conflict . Then check in the code and create a PR against master . This should work.

Answer (score -1):

You should push force your rebased branch to Github. Use `git push -f origin my-branch`.